# Retrieve only the images that user uploaded

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am using parse to upload and retrieve images.  I am using the below code to upload images.

```
  @IBAction func uploadButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        var imageText = uploadMessage.text

        if uploadPreviewImageView.image == nil {
            //image is not included alert user
            println("Image not uploaded")
        }else {

            var posts = PFObject(className: "Posts")
            posts["imageText"] = imageText
            posts["uploader"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.uploadPreviewImageView.image)
                    var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "uploaded_image.png", data: imageData)
                    posts["imageFile"] = parseImageFile
                    posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if error == nil {
```

As the title of the questions states, I would only want to retrieve images that the user has took.

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Tops")
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (posts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        for post in posts!{
            self.imageFiles.append(post["imageFile"]as! PFFile)
            self.imageText.append(post["imageText"]as! String)
    }


    println(self.imageFiles.count)
        self.topsTableView.reloadData()

} else {
        println(error)
}}}
```

In the above code I am able to retrieve images however if I log out and sign in to another account I am able to see the images that other users uploaded. How can this be possible? I was not able to find tutorials and documents that do this. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to define a predicate for your query. Parse supports `NSPredicate` and their own predicate-like mechanic.

For your purposes, you should set a condition for the query to only the pictures the user took. That can be expressed as `query.whereKey("uploader", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())`

In plain English, it's like saying - Hey query, return me results where the uploader property has a value of my current user.

You've set this property as you uploaded it :]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I'm a little confused. So we write `query.whereKey("uploader", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser() ` in the retrieve code?  Is there any documentation or  way of implementing  that I can see?

Comment: Yeah, insert this line right after you initialize your `PFQuery()`. You can read similar examples in the parse.com iOS guide, under the Queries section.